# make main view of app larger than the phone's screen

Tags: android

working on an app and The way I want to set it up is different than what I have ever done before. I want the main activity when launched into the app to exceed past the boundaries of the physical phone screen, and for the user to be able to swipe out to parts of the app that they can't originally see.

I am not sure what the terminology is or what methods or classes etc to use. Any info that could point me in the right direction would be great! Thanks!

Just some clarification:

I think what I'm trying to say is the second thing you talked about. Imagine if you place a iPhone for example in the middle of a piece of computer paper. What I want to achieve is to have the whole view the size of the paper, but only be able to see the size of the iPhone's screen at a time. So you can go up a little bit and see what was above the screen, or left or right

Answer (score 0):

If you want more screens and be able to switch between them, use ViewPager.

If you want one large view bigger than screen, you can either combine ScrollView for vertical scrolling and HorizontalScrollView for horizontal scrolling, or make some custom View, which will be able to scroll (you have to implement it on your own) in both direction.

If you want to have just some views outside of the screen and bring them to visible area on some event, you can use RelativeLayout and set to its views proper margin.

If you want something else, add more information, how it should look and act like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think what I'm trying to say is the second thing you talked about. Imagine if you place a iPhone for example in the middle of a piece of computer paper. What I want to achieve is to have the whole view the size of the paper, but only be able to see the size of the iPhone's screen at a time. So you can go up a little bit and see what was above the screen, or left or right

Comment: So, is that an answer to your question or would you like to know more?

Comment: I suppose the second one about horizontalScrollView is what I'm referring to. So if I combined horizontal and vertical I should have one huge view?

Comment: Yes, you can have one huge view. But remember, with combination of ScrollView and Horizontal ScrollView, you can scroll only in one direction at the time (either horizontally or vertically). And starting position is top left corner of the Big View.